# Need help looping through children of variable using express-handlebars

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, handlebars.js

I am working on an app. I am using Javascript and express, express-handlebars, and mysql.

I am trying to create a route that looks like '/viewowner/:ID/scoreboards/:year' where ID is a unique id to an owner, and year represents a year of data.

My SQL query relies on grabbing the id and year.

At the moment my a tag looks like:

```
{{#each output}}
<li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/viewowner//scoreboards/{{this}}">{{this}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

This iterates through the output array and gets me a list of the items in output. The link has the year attached but I have not been able to figure out how to get id into the link. The id variable is from a different array (s1), so using some JavaScript have isolated the id number and using .push(), pushed the id into the output array.

An example output array now looks like [2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,3]

I have tried to solve this issue by creating a new variable

```
var l = output.length

var yearlinks ={
    'years': output,
    'id': output.splice(l-1,1)
}
```

This however gives me two new arrays yearlinks.years which is an array with all the years, and yearlinks.id which just has the id number.

I have tried to loop through the children of yearlinks but that didn't work.

```
{{#each yearlinks}}
<li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/viewowner/{{id}}/scoreboards/{{#each years}}{{this}}{{/each}}">{{#each years}}{{this}}{{/each}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

Hoping someone has an idea of how to solve this, or can point me in a direction to learn how to solve this. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't push the `id` onto the `output` array. You just need an array of `years` and an `id`. `#each` over the `years` and, within the loop, grab the `id` from `../id`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! If I am looping through the years array 'output' using #each, how would I then grab the id if it isn't in output.

Comment: You would definitely need to include the years array and the id in the data object you pass in your `res.render` call - something similar to what you are doing with your `yearlinks` object. But you wouldn't `#each` over `yearlinks`. You should `#each` over `yearlinks.years` and reference the id at `../id` from within the loop.

Comment: hm that makes sense, but when I try it it doesn't work. I have taken out the id from the output array.  And yearlink.id now references the id.   `{{#each yearlinks.years}}
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/viewowner/{{yearlinks.id}}/scoreboards/{{this}}">{{this}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}` gets me a nice list of the years, but yearlinks.id is still blank in the link. If I console.log yearlinks.id I get the id.

Comment: I also tried     `{{#each yearlinks.years}}
    <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/viewowner/{{#with yearlinks.id}}{{this}}{{/with}}/scoreboards/{{this}}">{{this}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}` which didn't work.

Comment: Handlebars has evaluation contexts. `yearlinks.id` does not exist within the context of the `#each` loop. You need to use a path to access an object at a higher context. I think the path you need would be `../yearlinks.id`.

Comment: It worked! Awesome! Thanks so much for the help. I will now go read more of the documentation on handlebars and evaluation context!

Answer (score 0):

Evaluation Context in Handlebars

```
{{#each yearlinks.years}}
<li class="list-inline-item"><a href="/viewowner/{{../yearlinks.id}}/scoreboards/{{this}}">{{this}}</a></li>
  {{/each}}
```